# navigator.webkitPersistentStorage is deprecated; what is the alternative to increase storage quota?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, limit, deprecated, w3c

I'm storing JSON data in local storage and I must increase the 5MB quota with a cross-browser solution.  When trying some different things I've noticed that `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota()` which seemed the newest way to do it is deprecated.  What should I use ? I saw the Quota Management API by W3C but I didn't found any doc as of how it can be implemented in javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't possible to change the quota size with javascript, perhaps you should look into IndexedDB, the storage limit is a lot higher.

Comment: Thanks, IndexedDB solved my problem!